# Autocomplete InputField

Tags: dynamic, inputfield, autocomplete

Is there a way to define a `InputField` that displays a list of options as you type?  More specifically I'm looking for an `InputField` that specifically autocompletes as you type.

The functionality is similar to an `InputField` and `MenuView` element.

Examples of such feature would be the textbox [here](http://google.com) or [here](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

[image]

**EDIT:** Ideally the interface should work as much like Google's homepage as possible.

Specific Features

1. Menu is **not case sensitive**
2. **Clickable items** in drop down menu
3. Ideally, the menu is **hidden** until user types into textbox
4. Restrict number of items in output.

Here is [some example code](http://pastebin.com/4ag0LAJA) I am working on.  It currently only meets criteria #2.

**EDIT2:** Here is my [next set of code](http://pastebin.com/MPhaV3eR) which meets the following criteria: **case insensitive**, has clickable menus, and restricts the number of output.  One funny thing, is that the menu isn't clickable all the way across, but only where the text is.

Comment: Probably there is something better somewhere in SE so I'm posting it as comment: `Column[{InputField[Dynamic@x, String, ContinuousAction -> True], Pane[ Dynamic@Column[Names["System\`" ~~ x ~~ "*"]], {220, 300}]
  }]` You can start with this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My humble contribution:

```
(* Use this function to style list elements *)
listItemStyle[item_] := Mouseover[#, Style[#, Background -> LightBlue]] &@ MouseAppearance[Framed[item], "LinkHand"];

(* This filters the list of data and returns a clickable list *)
SetAttributes[autoComplete, HoldFirst];
autoComplete[s_, data_] := If[
  StringLength[s] > 0,
  EventHandler[#, {"MouseClicked" :> (s = #)}] & /@ Select[data, StringMatchQ[#, s ~~ __, IgnoreCase -> True] &],
  {}
  ]

(* Responsible for final output *)
SetAttributes[inputWithAutoComplete, HoldFirst];
inputWithAutoComplete[s_, data_, max_: 5] := Column[{
   InputField[Dynamic[s], String, ContinuousAction -> True],
   Dynamic[listItemStyle /@ (Take[#, Min[Length[#], max]] &@autoComplete[s, data] /. {} -> "") // TableForm]
   }, Left, 1]
```

Try it using:

```
data = CountryData[];
s = "";
inputWithAutoComplete[s, data, 10]
```

[image: dropdown]

**Version 2.0**

I started all over and refactored the code to make it better. There are many advantages so this is definitely the one to use, but I'm not deleting what I posted earlier since the new version is also substantially different, and both may be of interest.

```
(* Returns expr with styles off or on depending on whether the expr \
is hovered. Additionally the cursor as the mouse if hovering the \
expression can be set. *)

MouseoverStyled[expr_, off_, on_, cursor_: "LinkHand"] := Deploy[
  MouseAppearance[Mouseover[
    Style[expr, off],
    Style[expr, on]
    ], cursor]
  ]

(* Returns a list item with the given text *)

item[text_] := MouseoverStyled[Framed[text], {}, {Background -> LightBlue}]

(* Create a list of clickable items *)

items[labels_, func_] := EventHandler[
     item[#], {
      "MouseClicked" :> func[#]
      }
     ] & /@ labels;

(* Picks out the n first elements that start with input *)

filter[input_, data_, n_: 10] := Take[#, Min[Length[#], n]] &@Select[data, StringMatchQ[#, input ~~ __, IgnoreCase -> True] &]

(* Final presentation *)

inputWithAutoomplete[data_] := DynamicModule[{s = ""},
  Column[{
    InputField[Dynamic[s], String, ContinuousAction -> True],
    Dynamic@If[StringLength[s] > 0, Column[items[filter[s, data], (s = #) &]], ""]
    }]]
```

Test it like this:

```
inputWithAutoomplete[Last /@ CountryData[]]
```

or with just `CountryData[]` for more countries, but I noticed this can be quite slow (it didn't use to be - but since V10 with the `EntityValue` thing.)

Comment: +1 Much more compact then mine.  What version of Mathematica are you using?  currently in M8 the MouseClick's don't always seem to register for the drop down menu.

Comment: @LiamWilliam I'm using v.9, but that's not the problem;  by changing the background color and the cursor, I'm tricking you to believe you're hovering the clickable area. In fact you have to click on the text. I tried to correct it with `Pane` and some other things but ran out of time.

Comment: @LiamWilliam The new version does not have that problem, the entire framed box is now clickable!

Answer (score 11):

I also took a crack at this. I think I made it look pretty close to the jquery example you posted. Figuring out how to move the insertion point to the end of the word once a suggestion is selected was a bit of a struggle. As a result, there's a `DynamicWrapper` in there that may be unstable.

Input is the list of possible values from which you'd like to draw suggestions.

Enjoy!

```
autocompleteInputField[possibilities:{_String..}]:=DynamicModule[{nb,ind=0,txt,suggestions,suggestedElements,returnKeyTrigger=False},

suggestions = Dynamic[
                If[Length[suggestedElements] < 1 || StringLength[txt] <= 1,
                    "",
                (* else *)
                    Column[
                        MapIndexed[
                            Button[
                                Function[panel,Mouseover[Style[panel,Background->If[ind===First[#2],LightBlue,White]],Style[panel,Background->LightBlue]]]@Pane[#1,ImageMargins->0],
                                (
                                    txt=#1;
                                    returnKeyTrigger=True
                                ),
                                Appearance->"Frameless"
                            ]&,
                            If[!(If[Length[suggestedElements]===1,First[suggestedElements]===txt,False]) && StringLength[txt]>1,
                                suggestedElements,
                                {}
                            ]
                        ],
                        Background->White,
                        Frame->True
                    ]
                ]
            ];
Column[{
    DynamicWrapper[
        EventHandler[
            InputField[
                Dynamic[txt],
                String,
                ContinuousAction->True,
                BaseStyle->{FontFamily->"Arial"}
            ],
            {
                "DownArrowKeyDown":>(ind=Min[ind+1,Length[suggestedElements]]),
                "UpArrowKeyDown":>(ind=Max[0,ind-1]),
                "ReturnKeyDown":>
                    If[Length[suggestedElements]>0 && ind>0,
                        txt=suggestedElements[[ind]];
                        ind=0;
                        returnKeyTrigger=True
                    ]
            }
        ],
        If[returnKeyTrigger,
            returnKeyTrigger=False;
            SelectionMove[nb,Next,Word]
        ],
        SynchronousUpdating->False
    ],
    suggestions
}],

Initialization:>(
    nb = EvaluationNotebook[];
    txt="";
    suggestedElements:=Pick[possibilities,StringMatchQ[possibilities,txt~~__]]
    )

]
```

Comment: Best so far! Very nicely done. :)

Comment: @Anon I agree but those solutions has this problem that are not handy in context od GUIs. Try to fit this somewhere. ``Panel[autocompleteInputField[Names["System`*"]], 
 ImageSize -> {500, 200}, Alignment -> Center]``

Comment: @Kuba Yes, yours is the one that is the most useful solution, since in MMA we can't use a z-index to make the menu float above its surroundings. But taking the question on face value, this is the best answer :)

Comment: @Anon As I've said, I agree :) I'm wondering what type of object is that floating menu, I have no experience with other languages so can't compare.

Comment: @Kuba Yes I completely agree and this is a running problem. I was initially trying to use FrontEnd`AttachCell which seems to overlay the suggestions on top of its surroundings but couldn't figure out how to change the suggestions.

Comment: @Kuba I only have experience with HTML/CSS in which it's easy to make things float on top of each other. We might for example let one cell expand on top of another, by giving it a different z-value. Only objects with the same z-value push each other around.

Comment: @teedr What version of Mathematica are you using?  I tried running `autocompleteInputField[{"a", "ab", "abc"}]` in M9 but I have no visual output.

Comment: @LiamWilliam M9. Perhaps you didn't type in enough characters? The above snippet waits until at least 2 characters are input before making suggestions (you can easily change the code to remove that logic).

Comment: @teedr Thank you for the response.  Yes that seems to solve the issue `autocompleteInputField[{"abc", "abcd", "abcde"}]` works well.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe overkill but it was educational to try:

```
DynamicModule[{},
 EventHandler[
  Overlay[{
          Dynamic@Framed[
             Row[{Style[x, Transparent, 15, Bold], Style[rest, GrayLevel@.6, 15, Bold]}],
              ImageSize -> {280, 30}, Alignment -> Top, FrameMargins -> {{5, 0}, {0, 1}}],
          InputField[Dynamic@x, String, BaseStyle -> {Bold, Black, 15}, Alignment -> Top,
                     ContinuousAction -> True, ImageSize -> {280, 30}, FrameMargins -> 0]

          }, {2, 1}, 2]
         , {"ReturnKeyDown" :> (x = x ~~ rest), 
            "UpArrowKeyDown" :> (names = RotateLeft@names), 
            "DownArrowKeyDown" :> (names = RotateRight@names)}
             ]
 , Initialization :> (x = "";
     names := Names["System`" ~~ x ~~ "*"]; 
     rest := If[Length@names == 0 \[Or] x == "", "", 
                StringDrop[First[names], 
                Clip[StringLength@x, {0, StringLength@First[names]}]]]
                     )
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Please forgive me but I have no time to make it more user friendly.

There is no menu, only auto filling which you accept with <kbd>Enter</kbd> or you can also switch between fillings with arrows.

I have a couple of ideas, I'm going to write them tomorrow.

Comment: A little different then the original question but certainly a nice alternative.  Quit similar to a `MenuView` element. +1

Comment: @Liam Thanks, tell me more about what do You need it for. I will take this info under consideration while updating ;)

Comment: Your comment was slightly closer to the desired interface, because displayed a list of items.  I have updated the question with more explanation.

Comment: @Liam I know but " More specifically I'm looking for an InputField that specifically autocompletes as you type." :)

Comment: Well both versions do autocomplete, just in different ways ;) googles homepage is a good example, or the autocomplete doc search built into mathematica 9

Comment: @Liam I have failed to use `Menu...` built-in functions and I want them because You don't need to store a place for menu. It is overlayed on other content.

Answer (score 7):

**Note: This appears to really slowly in M9, although it works well in M8.  It probably is better to use teedr's until it can be figured out what is causing the slow speeds.**

The following seems to work pretty well.  I wrapped the options in a `Pane` and `Framed` so the entire row is clickable.

```
ClearAll[AutoInputField];
SetAttributes[AutoInputField, HoldAllComplete];

AutoInputField /: MakeBoxes[AutoInputField[field_,
    list_: {}, displayNum_: Infinity, imageSize_: 100], form_] := Module[{focus = False},

   With[{tag = SymbolName@Unique[StringJoin["g", ToString[$SessionID]]] },

    CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, {TaggingRules, tag, "x"}] = "";

    field = Dynamic@DynamicModule[{Only = Function[{l, n}, Take[l, Min[Length[l], n]]]},

       If[focus ||
         Not[CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, {TaggingRules, tag, "x"}] === ""]
        , Column[Map[Function[
           EventHandler[Framed[Pane[#,
              ImageSize -> Dynamic[(CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowSize][[1]] - 120)]
              ], FrameMargins -> 0, FrameStyle -> Gray], {

             "MouseClicked" :> (
               CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, {TaggingRules, tag, "x"}] = #
               )}]],

          Select[list, StringMatchQ[#,
              CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, {TaggingRules, tag, "x"}]
               ~~ ___, IgnoreCase -> True] &]~Only~displayNum]], ""]
       ];

    ToBoxes@EventHandler[
      InputField[
       Dynamic[
        CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, {TaggingRules, tag, "x"}]
        ],
       String, ContinuousAction -> True, ImageSize -> imageSize], {

       "ReturnKeyDown" :> ( (* focusForcedHidden *)
         CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, {TaggingRules, tag, "x"}] = 
              Append[
                Select[list, StringMatchQ[#,
                   CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, {TaggingRules, tag, "x"}]
                ~~ ___, IgnoreCase -> True] &]
            , ""][[1]];
         focus = False;
         ),
       "MouseEntered" :> ( (* focusForcedDisplay *)
         focus = True;
         ),
       "MouseExited" :> ( (* focusForcedDisplay *)
         focus = False;
         ),
       "MouseUp" :> ( (* If[x===list[[1]] && Length@list===1] *)
         focusForce = True;
         ),
       "KeyDown" :> ( 
         focusForce  = False;
         )
       },
      PassEventsDown -> True
      ]
    ]];
```

And the following outputs an AutoCompelete textbox.

```
(* AutoInputField[d,Map[(ToString[#])&,Table[i^2,{i,10}]]] *)
AutoInputField[d, {"ab", "abc", "100", "1", "16"}]
Pane[d,
 ImageSize -> {200, 80},
 Scrollbars -> True
 ]
```

Comment: Have you looked at [wormholes](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality.html#1497695040)?  I don't have time to check it out, but it might be away to avoid a global variable.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I hadn't seen wormwholes, those are quit cool.  I managed to refactor the code to something much shorter(although I unfortunately didn't use wormwholes).

Comment: I'm glad you are trying too. Notice that there is a problem with a place for such menu, you have to reserve it while built-in menu is displaying over the content. It would be also nice to scroll the content of current "help list", now it's fixed now. But mine is not ideal too, +1.

Comment: @Kuba Ideally it would be nice to hide the list except when the `InputField` is focused but I am not really sure how to force the input field to come into focus.

Comment: @Kuba I opened a question about [focus and InputField](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31073/detect-focus-of-inputfield).  As temporary  workaround I am using `MouseEntered` and `MouseExited` as a way to partially emulate focus.