# Detect when InputField gets keyboard focus

Tags: front-end, gui-construction, inputfield, eventhandler

How might I detect when an `InputField` comes into focus?

For example ideally something like this would work.

```
EventHandler[
 InputField["default", String], {
  "FocusGained" :> (MessageDialog["Focus"]),
  "FocusLost" :> (MessageDialog["unFocus"]),
  "Focus" :> (MessageDialog["Focus"])
  }
 ]
```

After reading [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6207/how-do-i-find-all-the-possible-events-that-work-with-eventhandler) I assumed "FocusGained,FocusLost or Focus" would do something but I haven't had any luck just yet.

Comment: A workaround may be to use "MouseClicked" to trigger "focus" and then use `ControllerState["Button 1"]` to trigger "unfocus", using "MouseEntered" and "MouseExited" to determine if the click was inside our outside the input box.

Comment: These are not events for `EventHandler` but events in [GUIKit](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/GUIKit/tutorial/Overview.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not anything documented that supports those events directly.

With so many folks digging up undocumented features I think it is safe to say that there isn't anything undocumented either.

There is a possibility of playing with indirect methods, e.g. listening to `SelectionData` etc. but I don't think it will give us a general tool, or a scalable one.

Maybe someonce will try to cook something up with this idea, meanwhile I think it is worth to take this on from an unanswered stack.

Comment: I'm assuming "meanwhile I think it is worth to take this on from an unanswered stack" means there is no sense in leaving this question unanswered when there is certainly not a clear answer.

Comment: @William something like that, maybe better "the answer is no but it may be that someone will provide a case specific trick".