# Is there a "LostFocus" event for controls?

Tags: gui-construction, eventhandler

In .Net controls have a [`LostFocus`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus(v=vs.110).aspx) event that fires when the control is no longer the active object; tabbing to next control or clicking somewhere else on the application. In Wolfram Language does [`EventHandler`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EventHandler.html) have a similar event?

The `"MouseMoved"` event cannot be used as this creates all manner of issues in a UI.   Is there a hidden equivalent to .Net's `LostFocus`?  If not can one be replicated without being dependent on the mouse events?

Comment: I don't think there is a general way: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31073/5478

Comment: AFAIK, Mathematica does make such events available to the user.

Comment: You do have `”MouseExited”` but nothing to do with focus that I’ve seen. Try selection tracking though. I think that works.

Comment: @b3m2a1 and Edmund, I've put there a CW answer to mark is as a duplicate and let future readers know what is the state of art. Feel free to edit it or let me know if you disagree with closing etc.

Comment: @Kuba Makes sense.  Thanks.