# AJAX-style HTTP calls triggered by a variable change

Tags: dynamic, import, inputfield

I'm trying to create a dynamic `InputField` that would autocomplete the address as I type it into the field, by calling Google Maps' GeoCoding API on every change of the field's value.

How can I make AJAX-style HTTP calls when the value of the `InputField` changes?

So for the only approach that I'm aware of is by using `UpValues`: [Detecting changes of variables' values](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41884/detecting-changes-of-variables-values)

Here's my code using `UpValues`:

```
DynamicModule[{addr, geo},

 addr /: Set[addr, x_] := (
   (
    OwnValues[addr] = {HoldPattern[addr] :> x}; 
    Print["Value changed"];
    geo = (Import["https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json",
          "JSON", "RequestParameters" -> {"address" -> x}] /. 
    List -> Association)["results"]
   ); 
   addr
  );

 addr = "555 Mission St, San Francisco";

 Column@
   {
   InputField[Dynamic[addr], String, ContinuousAction -> True],
   Dynamic[addr], Dynamic[geo["formatted_address"]]
   }
 ]
```

It kind of works, but for some reason not every change of the field's value triggers an API call.

Hence two questions:

1. Why are some of the change events lost?
2. Is there a better way to do AJAX-style HTTP calls when the value of a dynamic variable changes?

Also, these API calls via `Import` take ~200 ms, while they take much less time if I make them in a browser. Is there any way to speed them up?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just like Albert I recommend using the second argument of `Dynamic`. Furthermore I recommend that you embrace the first A in AJAX, which stands for "asynchronous", so the kernel isn't busy while it collects the data (this might be why some change events are lost with your code).

You can see how well the second argument of `Dynamic` works with this example:

```
Column[{
  InputField[
   Dynamic[s, (choices = RandomInteger[100, 10]; s = #) &],
   String,
   ContinuousAction -> True
   ],
  Dynamic@choices
  }]
```

Now I'll take the same code and add the code for fetching data asynchronously:

```
url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json";
callback[_, "data", data_] := choices = extractsAddresses@First@FromCharacterCode[data]

Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
extractsAddresses[data_] := ToAssociations[ImportString[data, "JSON"]][["results", All, "formatted_address"]]

fetchChoices[addr_] := URLFetchAsynchronous[
  url,
  callback,
  "Parameters" -> {"address" -> addr}
  ]

Column[{
  InputField[
   Dynamic[s, (fetchChoices[#]; s = #) &],
   String,
   ContinuousAction -> True
   ],
  Dynamic@choices
  }]
```

[image]

If you want to you can pair this strategy with the autocomplete `InputField` interfaces available [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28529/autocomplete-inputfield).

You can also take note of how I converted JSON into `Association`, which is undocumented but has been mentioned e.g. [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55789/731).

Comment: I just learned three new things about Mathematica from your and Albert's answers. Thanks so much!!

Comment: I have a quick clarifying question. When I wrap your code in a `DynamicModule` and declare `choices` as a local variable, it stops working. Do you know why that might be the case?

Comment: Well, depending on how you did it there are a few things that have to be fixed. I'm not sure about this atm, so your best bet is to ask a new question about it.

Comment: Thanks, Pickett. I posted a follow-up question here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86393/dynamic-does-not-update-when-wrapped-in-dynamicmodule?lq=1

Answer (score 10):

I think the standard way to do this is to use the second argument of `Dynamic`, e.g. like so:

```
With[{
  getCompletion = Function[
    Import[
     "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json", "JSON",
     "RequestParameters" -> {"address" -> #}
    ] //. {{r__Rule} :> (Association[r])}
  ]},
  DynamicModule[{
      addr = "555 Mission St, San Francisco",geo
    },
    geo = getCompletion[addr];
    Column@{
      InputField[
        Dynamic[addr, (addr = #; geo = getCompletion[#]) &],
        String, ContinuousAction -> True
      ],
     Dynamic[addr], Dynamic[geo[["results", 1, "formatted_address"]]]
   }
 ]
]
```