# If I have a very large Popup Menu list how can I make that searchable?

Tags: front-end, gui-construction

Imagine that you have a `PopupMenu's` list that requires a lot of scrolling through the selections. Is there a way to create a control that will only display a subsection of the complete list?

Comment: How closely related is that: [Autocomplete InputField](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28529/5478)?

Comment: @Kuba closely related. In this present case the usage requirement was minimise the choices in a large popup but the autocomplete input field looks like an alternative solution to the same, or similar, problem. The reason why the solution you have linked is not useful to me is that is inserts a column of menu choices into your interface whereas a popup is overlayed on top. Therefore the popup does not disrupt your interface design layout. It would be nice if the popup could automatically open when you type in the input field

Comment: @kuba please see my edit

Comment: I've seen, thanks for clarification. :)

Answer (score 24):

I have finished a project where widgets like this have been useful so I thought I would share. By combining InputField and PopupMenu a searchable popup selection table can be created.

```
searchPopup[Dynamic[selection_], list_List] := 
 DynamicModule[{x = ""},
  Grid[{{
     InputField[Dynamic[x], String,
      Appearance -> "Frameless",
      ContinuousAction -> True,
      FieldHint -> "Search",
      FieldSize -> 10],
     Spacer[5],
     Dynamic[
      PopupMenu[Dynamic[selection,(selection = #; x = #) &], 
       Cases[list, 
        z_String /; StringMatchQ[z, x ~~ ___, IgnoreCase -> True]], 
       Null,
       Opener[True, Appearance -> Small]],
      TrackedSymbols :> {x}]
     }},
   Alignment -> {{Right, Left}, Center},
   Background -> White,
   Frame -> True,
   FrameStyle -> GrayLevel[0.8]]
  ]

list = {"Ajax", "admixes", "Acrux", "Alex", "affix", "admixtures", 
   "Alexei", "affixed", "admixing", "ambidextrously", "admixed", 
   "admix", "affixing", "ambidextrous", "Alexandrians", "Alexandria", 
   "Anaxagoras", "Alexandrian", "annexation", "Alexandra", 
   "admixture", "Alexis", "Alexanders", "annex", "affixes", 
   "ambidexterity", "Alexander"};
selection = "";

searchPopup[Dynamic[selection], list]
```

[image]

**Edit**

To address @kuba's comment by way of example in the GIF we have a toy interface. Normally you would not want your interface elements moving around all over the place. Therefore using popup menu is a good way to achieve this search menu objective.

[image]

Comment: This `Popup` code is indeed very useful. I have a `Manipulate` which has two `PopupMenu`s with a very long list. But I am having trouble incorporating your `searchPopup[Dynamic[selection], list]` into the `Manipulate`. Could you guide me in using it?

Answer (score 16):

Based on undocumented `` FrontEnd`AttachCell ``:

- [**What is `` FrontEnd`AttachedCell ``?**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/99292/5478)

And `` Experimental`Autocomplete ``but this can be replaced with Mike's approach.

Need to work on style, automatic scrolling and some edge cases, but already  works quite well. Feedback appreciated.

```
Column[{
  searchPopup2[Dynamic[selection], list],
  Graphics@Disk[]
  }]
```

[image]

#### Code

```
    searchPopup2[Dynamic[var_], list_] := 
 DynamicModule[{thisBox, currentList = {}, autocompleteF, 
   attachedCell, dynamicFunction, whatToDo, lastLength, cPos = 1, 
   itemWrapper, attachTo, dropMenu, menu}, 
   EventHandler[
     InputField[Dynamic[First@List@var, dynamicFunction], String, 
      FieldHint -> "Search", 
      ContinuousAction -> 
       True], {"MouseClicked" :> (If[ Length@currentList > 0, attachedCell = attachTo[thisBox, menu[currentList]]]), 
      "DownArrowKeyDown" :> (cPos = 
         Mod[cPos + 1, Length@currentList, 1]), 
      "UpArrowKeyDown" :> (cPos = 
         Mod[cPos - 1, Length@currentList, 1]), "ReturnKeyDown" :> (
        lastLength = Length@currentList;
        currentList = autocompleteF[var];
        If[Length[currentList] > 0, var = currentList[[cPos]]; 
         FinishDynamic[]]; dropMenu[])}, PassEventsDown -> True], 
  SynchronousInitialization -> False, 
  Initialization :> (thisBox = EvaluationBox[];
    autocompleteF = Autocomplete[list];
    currentList = autocompleteF@var;

    dynamicFunction = (var = #;
       lastLength = Length@currentList;
       currentList = autocompleteF[var];

       whatToDo[]) &;

    whatToDo[] := 
     Which[lastLength != 0 && Length[currentList] == 0, dropMenu[], 
      Or[lastLength == 0 && Length[currentList] > 0, 
       And[lastLength != 0 && Length[currentList] != 0, 
        Not@MatchQ[attachedCell, _CellObject]]], 
      attachedCell = attachTo[thisBox, menu[currentList]]];

    attachTo[parentbox_, what_] := 
     MathLink`CallFrontEnd[
      FrontEnd`AttachCell[parentbox, 
       ToBoxes[ExpressionCell[what, StripOnInput -> True, 
         Background -> White, CellFrameColor -> GrayLevel@.8, 
         CellFrameMargins -> 0, CellFrame -> 2]], {Automatic, {Left, 
         Bottom}}, {Left, Top}, 
       "ClosingActions" -> {"ParentChanged", "EvaluatorQuit", 
         "OutsideMouseClick"}]];

    SetAttributes[menu, HoldFirst];
    menu[currentList_] := 
     EventHandler[
      Pane[Dynamic[
        Column[MapIndexed[itemWrapper, currentList], Spacings -> 0], 
        TrackedSymbols :> {currentList}], {200, {All, 300}}, 
       AppearanceElements -> None, Scrollbars -> {False, True}], 
      "MouseExited" :> (dropMenu[];)];
    itemWrapper[item_, {pos_}] := 
     MouseAppearance[#, "LinkHand"] &@
      EventHandler[
       Framed[item, ImageSize -> {Full, Automatic}, 
        FrameStyle -> None, 
        Background -> 
         Dynamic[If[pos == cPos, CurrentValue@"PanelBackground", 
           White]]], {"MouseClicked" :> (pos == cPos;
          var = item;
          dropMenu[];
          lastLength = Length@currentList;
          currentList = autocompleteF[var];),
        "MouseEntered" :> (cPos = pos)}, PassEventsDown -> True];
    dropMenu[] := (
      If[MatchQ[attachedCell, _CellObject],
       NotebookDelete[attachedCell];
       attachedCell =.
       ])
    )]
```

Comment: I did not know about `FrontEnd\`AttachCell`. That could be useful. Did you learn about it by spelunking something? Do you know of anyway to have a branched pulldown or popup menu. For example, instead of using the second argument of dynamic to populate a menu in another popup could the second menu appear next to the first menu and be populated based on the selection in the first menu? We see this on web pages. If you know how to do this i can ask this as a question and you can post the answer.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch could you link where I can take a look at such functionality? I will answer when take a closer look. All I know about `AttachCell` is posted in the topic I've linked on top. p.s. have to go now, it's quite late(early) :P Will be in touch.

Comment: I am finishing now too. I'll se if I can find a pull down menu that shows the functionality.

Comment: very nice, but I think there is a typo which made my mathematica complain: there is a double ';;' after `EvaluationBox[];;` in the `Initialization` which makes Mathematica complain and the widget not work.

Comment: @AlbertRetey correct, thanks :)

Comment: @ Kuba - Good work with AttachCell! Theres a couple features that I'm working on adding to your code. For example I noticed that clicking inside the blank search field results in a scrollable list where all elements are not in alphabetical order. In fact, even when a list is restricted to a smaller subset by typing in a few characters, the resulting list is not quite in alphabetical order. It is in "an" order but it doesn't seem obvious to me what that order is and how to make it alphabetical. Simply changing the order of the elements in list does not seem to fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: @michael can't test now but it propably depends if the initial lost is sorted or not, here it wasn't.

Comment: Yes.  I assumed as much but it doesn't seem to match up even with a sorted list.