# Create a ActionMenu like Windows

Tags: menu

I want to put G-1 CRD and G-2 CRD  inside Fac.Pharmacy something like this:
[image]

I I have this to start:

```
Module[{}, 
 With[{
       g1 = Import[FileNameJoin[{Directory[], 
       "Mi proyecto/Registros/Farmacia CRD/2do Año", "grupo1.txt"}], 
     "List", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"]}, 
  ActionMenu[
   "Import Groups", {Item["Fac.Pharmacy"], "G-1 CRD" :> g1, 
    "G-2 CRD" :> Print["action2"], Delimiter, Delimiter, 
    Item["Fac.Foods"], "G-1 CPE" :> "action1", 
    "G-2 CPE" :> "action2"}]]]
```

Comment: Is this what you need? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102586/5478 unfortunately the answer does not seem to work in most recent mma version, will try to take a look at that.

Comment: @Kuba.Yes, it's really what I need.The code doesn't work in MMA v11.3.I will wait for your answer. Thanks.