# Multilevel ActionMenu

Tags: dynamic, menu

I am trying to build a multi-level ActionMenu. A single level ActionMenu is easy following the documents, such as `ActionMenu["Single Level", {"1" :> Print[1], "2" :> Print[2],  "3" :> Print[3]}]` However, I don't know how to expand this to multi-level selection. A naive code such as `ActionMenu["Multi-Level", {"1" :>  ActionMenu["Level 2", {"a" :> Print[a], "b" :> Print[b]}],  "2" :> Print[2], "3" :> Print[3]}]` didn't work. Please help...

Comment: related/possible duplicate: [How to make a dynamic nested menu?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102586/125)

Comment: Agreed, this look like a solution to this question.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`AttachCell`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AttachCell.html) with [`EvaluationBox`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EvaluationBox.html). `AttachCell` is an experimental function in version 12.2 so behaviour may change.

I `AttachCell` a new [`ActionMenu`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ActionMenu.html) below the evaluating `ActionMenu` using `EvaluationBox`. The attached menu deletes itself and performs the action. The other options also delete the attached menu before performing their actions.

```
Module[
 {acell}
 , ActionMenu[
  "Multi-Level"
  , {
   "1" :> (
     NotebookDelete[acell]
     ; acell =
      AttachCell[
       EvaluationBox[]
       , ActionMenu[
        "Level 2"
        , {
         "a" :> (NotebookDelete[acell]; Print[a])
         , "b" :> (NotebookDelete[acell]; Print[b])
         }
        ]
       , {Left, Bottom}, Automatic, {Left, Top}
       ]
     )
   , "2" :> (NotebookDelete[acell]; Print[2])
   , "3" :> (NotebookDelete[acell]; Print[3])
   }
  ]
 ]
```

> [image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this is a cool solution. I didn't know the AttachCell function previously, seems like a pretty new function. However, I am trying to implement this on a palettes, not sure how it will work out.