# Displaying ActionMenu Choices Programmatically

Tags: gui-construction, menu

Executing the following code creates an ActionMenu:

```
ActionMenu["Menu", {"temp1" :> Print[1], "temp2" :> Print[2]}]
```

If you move the mouse over the ActionMenu and then mouse click you will see the possible choices appear as shown below.

[image]

I am trying to find a way to get the choices to appear without moving the mouse or clicking it.  Instead, I would like to achieve it programmatically with no mouse input.  A keyboard solution with no mouse input would also suffice.  Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think you can do this with ActionMenu except of maybe using JLink to simmulate mouse click. But you can create your own menu based on AttachedCells that you will have control over. Here is an example: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102586/5478 but it does not expose any methods to control it remotely, you would need to adapt it.

Comment: @Kuba  I appreciate the direction!  Attachcell seem very useful.