# How to create my own inline drop down autocompletion in a text cell?

Tags: keyboard, autocomplete

Mathematica has a nice dropdown feature when typing along in an input cell.  If I type "Pl" a dropdown appears with options on how I can complete the command.  It's basically a shortcut.  I can then press the down arrow to choose one.

[image]

This is great.  I would like to add this functionality to a text cell.  In addition I want the drop down to include strings and boxes that I create. For the boxes I would have to somehow tie it to a string so that it would be searchable as I type in characters.

For example, if I am in a text cell and start to type the word "limit" I want to get a drop down menu with narrowing choices as I type more characters.  Some of these choices might include the word "limit" or the limit notation in textbook format with a placeholder set to move in and out of.  I would just need to press the down arrow to chose which one I wanted.

I think I would prefer a shortcut feature like this over autoinputreplacements and inputaliases.  I use them a lot but they are a pain.  I have some experience creating something in a docked cell using ideas from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102470/if-i-have-a-very-large-popup-menu-list-how-can-i-make-that-searchable/102477#102477)  But I'm looking for something that works inline as I type in a text cell if that makes sense.

Is this possible?  Is there a way to access Mathematica's autocomplete feature and make it work in a text cell with my own strings and boxes populating the dropdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't customizable in the way you want, but you can get spelling word auto-completions in a text cell.  Just open a text cell, type limit and hit Ctrl+K.  That might help a bit.

Comment: That's interesting.  I did not know that.  That's a cool feature.  It won't save me any time, but still cool to know.  Do you think there is a way to type in a word like "limit" and then some key combination after to get a drop down that I can populate with my own box data?  This would not be an autocomplete feature.  It would be more of a... "choose and replace".

Comment: I'm trying to find ways to make typing textbook notation in a text cell faster.  I use inputaliases and autoinputreplacements but thinking about creating other methods that may work better in my work flow.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work.

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, NotebookEventActions -> {  
   "KeyDown" :> {FrontEndTokenExecute["CompleteSelection"]}
   , PassEventsDown -> True}]
```

at least for words.