# How to speed up a text search widget?

Tags: string-manipulation, gui-construction, inputfield, searching

I have an `InputField` that searches a predefined list for matching strings and displays them in a `TextGrid`. But when the list is large, the front end hangs:

[image]

Using `Cases` is obviously slow, but I don't want to use the fourth argument to limit the number of matches, so can't see any simple way to speed it up:

```
Clear @ SearchStrings
SearchStrings[input_:""] := DynamicModule[{$input=input, matches = {}},
 Panel @ Column @ {
  Row[{InputField[Dynamic[$input], String,
   FieldHint->"Enter company", FieldHintStyle->{Gray},
   BaseStyle->{"ControlStyle"},ContinuousAction->True,
   FieldSize->13], Dynamic @ Text @ Style[" (" <> ToString @ Length[matches]<> " rows)", 11, FontFamily->"Verdana",
    FontWeight->"Thin", FontColor->Gray]}, "   "],
  Pane[
   Dynamic[
    TextGrid[
     Map[{Button[Text @ Style[#, 13, FontFamily->"Verdana",
        FontWeight->"Thin", FontColor->Black], 
        CopyToClipboard[#], Appearance->"Frameless"]}&,
      matches = Cases[$sites, s_/;StringContainsQ[s,$input], {-1}]
     ],
     ItemSize->{40,Automatic}, Dividers->All, Spacings->2, FrameStyle -> Directive[Thickness[Tiny], LightGray]
    , Selectable -> False],
   TrackedSymbols :> {$input}],
        Scrollbars->{False,True}, ImageSize->{230,200}]}
]

$sites = ToString /@ Range[10000];

SearchStrings[""]
```

Comment: Side note, there is `FieldCompletionFunction` option for `InputField` now.

Comment: related autocompletion topics: [102470](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102470/5478), [28529](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28529/5478) related grid interface topic: [21117](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21117/5478)

Comment: p.s. `Cases` is not slow. Typesetting and rendering of the long list of matched entries is. That is the problem in the 21117 question too.

Comment: Thanks, I did know about FieldCompletionFunction - but wanted to implement more permanent view of the results. Do you think something like UITableView that supports streaming data into a scrolling view is possible to write ourselves?

Comment: Yes, but at a cost of items size flexibility and using custom scrollbars which will not render as nicely as OS versions. Plus it needs to be created too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bottleneck is the fact that `Pane` 'cares' about full content even when only the fraction is needed. We need `Pane` that fits our needs better.

The solution is based on a beta version of `VerticalScrollbar` and `ListPane`, if you find it hard to customize, let me know about options it should take, syntax etc.

It was only tested on Win7.

Let me know what changes you;d like to see in a polished version.

[image]

```
VerticalScrollbar // ClearAll ;

VerticalScrollbar // Options = {
  "PageSize" -> .2
, ImageSize -> Automatic  
};

VerticalScrollbar[Dynamic[scrollPosition_], OptionsPattern[] ]:=With[
  { pageSize = OptionValue["PageSize"]
  , MPY     := MousePosition[{"GraphicsScaled", Graphics}, {0,0}][[2]]
  , thumbCol = GrayLevel @ .9
  , thumbColActive = GrayLevel @ .8
  , scrollHeight = .2
  , imageSize  = OptionValue[ImageSize] /. Automatic -> {15, Full}

  }
, DynamicModule[
    { 
      showScrollbar,            
      scrollRawPosition = 1 - (scrollPosition + scrollHeight),
      mousePositionStart,
      scrollRawPositionOffset = 0,
      clipSRPos = Function[pos, Clip[pos, {0 , 1 - scrollHeight }]],
      col = GrayLevel[.9]
    }
  , 
   Module[
      {pane, scrollbar}

    , scrollbar = Graphics[
        DynamicNamespace @ { EdgeForm@Black, Dynamic@If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], thumbColActive, thumbCol]
        , Rectangle[{0, Dynamic[scrollRawPosition]}, {1, Dynamic[scrollRawPosition + scrollHeight]}, BoxID -> "thumb"]      
        , Black, Inset["=", DynamicLocation["thumb", None, Center]]
        }      
      , ImageSize        -> imageSize
      , PlotRange        -> {{0,1}, {0,1}}
      , PlotRangePadding -> {2. / 15, 2./200}
      , ImageMargins->0
      , PlotRangeClipping->False
      , AspectRatio->Full


      , ImagePadding->None
      , Background->GrayLevel@.95
      ]

    ; scrollbar = EventHandler[
        scrollbar
      , {
          "MouseDown" :> (
            mousePositionStart = MPY
          ; Which[            (*inside, maybe better vie MouseEntered?*)
              mousePositionStart < scrollRawPosition
            , scrollRawPosition = clipSRPos[scrollRawPosition - pageSize]

            , mousePositionStart > scrollRawPosition + scrollHeight  
            , scrollRawPosition = clipSRPos[scrollRawPosition + pageSize]

            , True, scrollRawPositionOffset = MPY - scrollRawPosition 
            ]
          )
        , "MouseDragged" :> (
            scrollRawPosition = clipSRPos[MPY - scrollRawPositionOffset]
          )

        }  
      ]  
        (* visibility *)
    ; scrollbar = PaneSelector[
        { True -> scrollbar, False-> Spacer[0]}
      , Dynamic[showScrollbar]
      ]
        (* listener*)
    ; scrollbar = DynamicWrapper[scrollbar    
      , scrollPosition = 1 - Rescale[scrollRawPosition, {0 , 1-scrollHeight}, {0, 1}]
      , TrackedSymbols :> {scrollRawPosition}
      ]


    ; scrollbar  
    ]
  ]
];
```

```
ListPane // ClearAll;

ListPane // Options = {
   ImageSize -> {All, 200},
   "ItemWrapper" -> (Pane[##, ImageMargins->0]&)
};

ListPane[Dynamic[list_], OptionsPattern[]]:=With[
  {
    paneHeight = OptionValue[ImageSize][[2]],
    itemHeight = 25,
    totalLength = Length[list],
    imageSize = OptionValue[ImageSize],
    itemWrapper = OptionValue["ItemWrapper"]
  }
, DynamicModule[
    {
      visibleLength = Ceiling[paneHeight/itemHeight],
      visiblePart,
      position = 1,
      scrollPosition = 0

    }
  , visibleLength = Ceiling[paneHeight/itemHeight]
  ; visiblePart = Take[list,UpTo[visibleLength]]


  ; Module[
      {pane}

    , pane = Dynamic[ (*TODO: preburn*)
        Column[
          itemWrapper[#, ImageSize->{Full, itemHeight},ImageMargins->0, Alignment->{Left,Center}]&/@visiblePart
        , Spacings->0
        ]
      ]
    ; Panel[
        Grid[{{
          pane
        , DynamicWrapper[
            VerticalScrollbar[Dynamic@scrollPosition, ImageSize -> {15, paneHeight}]
          , position = Round @ Rescale[scrollPosition, {0,1}, {1, totalLength}]
          ; visiblePart = Take[list, {position, UpTo[position + visibleLength]}]
          , TrackedSymbols:>{scrollPosition}
          ]

        }}, Spacings->{1,0},Alignment->{Left,Top}]
      , ImageSize->{imageSize[[1]], paneHeight+visibleLength-1}
      , FrameMargins->0
      , Alignment->{Right,Top}
      , BaseStyle->CacheGraphics->False
      ] 
    ]
  ]
];
```

### And your updated code

```
Clear@SearchStrings
SearchStrings[input_: ""] := 
 DynamicModule[{$input = input, matches = {}},
  Panel[
   Column@{Row[{
       InputField[Dynamic[$input], String, 
        FieldHint -> "Enter company", FieldHintStyle -> {Gray}, 
        BaseStyle -> {"ControlStyle"}, ContinuousAction -> True, 
        FieldSize -> 13],
       Dynamic@
        Text@Style[" (" <> ToString@Length[matches] <> " rows)", 11, 
          FontFamily -> "Verdana", FontWeight -> "Thin", 
          FontColor -> Gray]
       }, "   "
      ],
     DynamicWrapper[
      Dynamic[
       ListPane[
        Dynamic[matches], ImageSize -> {Full, 200}, 
        "ItemWrapper" -> (Button[
            Text@Style[#, 13, FontFamily -> "Verdana", 
              FontWeight -> "Thin", FontColor -> Black], 
            CopyToClipboard[#], Appearance -> "Frameless", ##2] &)
        ],
       TrackedSymbols :> {matches}
       ],
      matches = Cases[$sites, s_ /; StringContainsQ[s, $input], {-1}],
      TrackedSymbols :> {$input}
      ]

     }
   ,
   ImageSize -> {300, All}]
  ]

$sites = ToString /@ Range[10000];

Deploy@SearchStrings[""]
```

Comment: What does preburn mean in your todo?